# Login with email instead of username

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony6

I have a fresh install of Symfony 6 and trying to login with email instead of (default) username

`security.yaml`

```yaml
providers:
  app_user_provider:
  entity:
    class: App\Entity\User
    property: email
firewalls:
  main:
    lazy: true
    provider: app_user_provider
    json_login:
      check_path: api_login
```

The behaviour is correct: auth mechanism is using `email` field in the db to do the login. The problem is that I have to pass an `username` parameter instead of `email` when I log in, otherwise I get this error:
[image: bad request]
Any idea how to change the config to accept `email`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [there](https://symfony.com/doc/5.2/security/json_login_setup.html) you can use this :

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        main:
            anonymous: true
            lazy: true
            json_login:
                check_path:    login
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
```